# Adding a new join to a view

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner when it comes to SQL and I'm trying to add a new table with a left join in the code below due to a crm upgrade and change in the structure.

I now need to insert a join between calls and contacts using the calls_contacts table linked on calls.id via calls.contact_id on contacts.id

```
FROM
    ((`users`
    JOIN ((`calls`
    LEFT JOIN (`contacts`
    LEFT JOIN `contacts_cstm` ON ((`contacts_cstm`.`id_c` = `contacts`.`id`))) ON ((`calls`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id`)))
    JOIN `calls_cstm` ON ((`calls`.`id` = `calls_cstm`.`id_c`))) ON ((`users`.`id` = `calls`.`assigned_user_id`)))
    JOIN ((`accounts_cstm`
    JOIN `accounts` ON ((`accounts_cstm`.`id_c` = `accounts`.`id`)))
    JOIN `teams` ON ((`accounts`.`team_id` = `teams`.`id`))) ON ((`calls`.`parent_id` = `accounts`.`id`)))
```

Any help greatly appreciated, keen to learn!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: It's MySQL sorry!